# How do I make the disk decryption password prompt show up on my DVI-D monitor with an AMD video card?

Tags: grub2, graphics, radeon, monitor, nomodeset

I have a Dell box running Ubuntu 15.04. Because it's a work machine, its disk if fully encrypted, and therefore the system requires a disk decryption password at boot time.

Because I needed to connect this box to my personal monitor (HP LP3065, a 30" monitor with DVI-D input), I replaced the video card that came with the machine with an AMD Radeon HD 5570 (a low profile video card I had on hand).

The problem is the following: the disk decryption prompt does not show up on the monitor. I can type in the password blindly, and when the system proceeds to the normal login prompt, the monitor starts getting signal. Up until that point, the monitor stays black.

I've tried adding "nomodeset" to the grub string, but that caused the machine to hang at the disk decryption password prompt, it wouldn't even let me enter the password. I also tried adding "Radeon.modeset=0", but that doesn't seem to do anything.